# Azure Logic App ignores indent="yes" when transforming XML

Tags: azure, xslt, biztalk, azure-logic-apps

I'm using Azure Logic App to transform a CSV file to XML, everything was initially set up in BizTalk first to generate the relevant XSDs and XSL which worked perfectly fine.  But when I use Azure Logic App the output XML file is all in one line even though I made sure it has `indent="yes"` in the XSL file.

[image]

I know I can use notepad++ to pretty print the result and save the file, but surely there's a way to automatically do that in Logic App?

Comment: Does that happen perhaps rather by the XML Validation 2 step? It is more likely that the validation strips any indentation. But I haven't tested.

Comment: Unfortunately not, even though I took it out it was still doing the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I've found a setting within the Logic App, simply select Apply XSLT output attributes and that's it, no validation needed either!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get indentation when using XSLT 3.0 with e.g. the stylesheet/map doing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then a request of e.g.

```
<root><item>a</item><item>b</item></root>
```

is transformed to the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item>a</item>
   <item>b</item>
</root>
<!--Run with SAXON HE 9.8.0.8 -->
```

I don't know how they run the XSLT 1.0 processor to ignore the `xsl:output` settings, seems a flaw or quirk in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks I could give that a go, do you know if there's anything out there which can readily convert XSLT1.0 to XSLT3.0 by any chance?

Comment: @tommyhmt, well, technically any XSLT 3.0 processor should be able to process a `version="1.0"` stylesheet, and as they use Saxon there on Azure, it is an XSLT 3 processor that, when encountering an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, supports XPath 1.0 compatibility mode which would be the mayor factor to ensure that the result of expressions like `<xsl:value-of select="foo"/>` is outputting the string value of the first `foo` child element (XSLT 1 behaviour) and not the concatenation of the string values of all `foo` child elements.

Comment: So pure XSLT 1 thrown at Saxon 9.8 instead of XslCompiledTransform should work rather well, I think. Of course, if your XSLT 1.0 makes use of Microsoft specific extensions like `msxsl:script` to call into .NET, you won't get that to work with Saxon without rewriting as much as you can in pure XSLT 3 or switching to the Saxon way of calling into .NET.